# how to pass value from spec file to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I want to write rspec test to existing code. Existing code is

```
def getperson
  log_middle('getperson') do
    @filteredPersons = Person.where(['UserID=?', @@userID])
  end
  @filteredPersons
end
```

I want to assign value `@@userID` from rspec file. How to assign value to it in person_spec file

Comment: How you assign value to it in "production" code?

Comment: I just want to write Unit test to that method

Comment: You are not testing that method, you are testing the class behaviour by calling that method. So you need to "know" how `@@userId` is set in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `class_variable_set` like [an actionmailer test setup here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/test/base_test.rb#L1015)(although this is MiniTest setup but the idea is same, you could use for rspec as well).

so your test case look like this

```rb
# test_helper
def with_user_id(user_id)
  old_user_id = ClassUnderTest.class_variable_get(:@@userID)
  ClassUnderTest.class_variable_set(:@@userID, user_id)
  yield
ensure
  ClassUnderTest.class_variable_set(:@@userID, old_user_id)
end

# your test
with_user_id(123) do
  get_person ...
  expect(...)
end
```

or if you don't care side effect:

```rb
# ...
context "@@userID is 123" do
  before(:each) do
    ClassUnderTest.class_variable_set(:@@userID, 123)
  end

  it "should ..." do
    getperson ...
    expect(...).to ...
  end
end
# ...
```